# How to see the list of "used devices" in Facebook "login notification" feature?

Tags: facebook, notifications, login

It seems that I'm not receiving SMS notification messages when I try to log in from a new device.

Where can I see the list of "used devices"? I want to reset the list so as to receive a notification.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a little bit further down the same page. It's labeled "Recognized Devices". It will show you a list of all of the devices/browsers that you have authorized to log in without notification.

`Account Settings | Security`

[image]